# How to Show SonarQube's Comment Widget

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube4.2, and I'm trying to confirm comment line number in my source codes. I could inspect these source codes using SonarQube, but SonarQube only shows dupulication without comments on dashboard.[image]

How can I confirm comments line number using SonarQube. Could anybody help me?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Custom Measures widget and select the comment-related metrics.

Comment: Thank you for your kind. I understand it. Now I could confirm a comment line number on dashboard. Regards